# How do I add data labels to simplexplots or archetype objects in R?

Tags: r, visualization, archetypes

Using the archetypes function in R I am able to get 3 archetypes.

```
a = archetypes(raw_data,3)
a$archetypes
```

I have gotten 3 archetypes

```
[1,]  0.3269066   0.17333403  0.6758994 0.03486667
[2,]  0.1194622   0.06533782  0.2380678 0.98290574
[3,]  0.7475306   0.64516930  0.9760400 0.35975058
```

I now want to visualize where the data falls in relation to the archetypes themselves.
[image: Output of simplexplot]

I have tried using the labels argument when calling the simplexplot, but it just gives a long string of numbers rather than the actual data labels.

A graph is not even necessary, but I want to understand which row from my data set is most similar to which archetype. Any help is appreciated!